# Python Mysqldb insert error

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using MySQLdb and Python to insert data into the local database.

The insert query is

```
for row in v1:
    cur2.execute("""""INSERT INTO s_test (CO1,CO2, CO3, CO4, CO5) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);""""",(row[0],row[1], row[2],row[3], row[4]));
```

I get the error

`IndexError: tuple index out of range`

If I use the query below, I get no errors

```
for row in v1:
    cur2.execute("INSERT INTO s_test (CO1) VALUES (%s);",(row[0]));
```

If I increase the number of columns into which I insert, I get the same error mentioned above.

What is the correct syntax?

Comment: check in db are you able to insert the data in table with your above statement

Answer (score 0):

I don't remember much about Python, but this sounds like you don't have 5 elements in the row array, more than a SQL error. Can you check that?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the data's entirely numerical, you could try this:

```
cur2.execute("""INSERT INTO s_test (CO1, CO2, CO3, CO4, CO5) VALUES ({0}, {1}, {2}, {3}, {4});""".format(row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3], row[4]);
```

Use 3 quotes instead of 5; replace the comma with a period; use the more modern `.format` string substitution.